# What kind of sea conditions would my 'Warp' have that wouldstop submarines from being able to operate effectively?

Tags: environment, military, navy

In my creation of a semi-realistic armed forces for my world's main faction, I took the unrealistic decision to make a way of keeping battleships. To that end, I adapted my existing idea of creating a 'magic' interdimensional plane, which is effectively a large ocean that  allows for interplanetary travel.

One established condition in this plane is that the air is too 'stormy' for aircraft like planes to function properly, or for long range missiles to be guided accurately. However, I can't think of an equivalent set of properties that would make submarine warfare constrained to planetary bodies of water, leaving the Warp to conventional surface combatants.

TL;DR
What kind of properties would this large sea have that would make submarine's incapable of being used as effective weapons?

Answer (score 3):

### Denser waters

The warp sea might be able to be sailed on top of, the waters being displaced as usual, but do not be a fool to try and go under. The waters are heavy and hard to swim through. While no swimmer or normal vessel will likely sink into these heavy waters, causing floating bodies and islands of shipwrecks, a heavy and almost purely metallic submarine designed to go underwater and stay there will face much greater mounting pressures than in the normal bodies of water it was designed to be in, and will likely be crushed like a tin can before long, forcing any submarines in the warp sea to stay at the surface like all other ships. The dense waters also make it harder for torpedoes to do their underwater and meant to be more or less hidden until impact jobs as well, because they can now be shot at from the surface and rendered ineffective, so cannon or other artillery fire is opted for instead.

While you could design something that can withstand the pressures of the warp sea in a similar manner to how we have designed things to withstand the deepest of our oceans, judging by how we've managed to make them not crack under the pressure I doubt they will be very large vessels or capable of carrying much in the way of firepower.

You could also make the warp sea's water be a non-neutonian fluid and act like oobleck, which is going to be a very bad day for things like turbine propellers, rendering submarine and torpedo mobility to essentially nothing in the warp sea unless they go really slowly.

Comment: yes! mercury seas are very a propos for the warp.

Comment: This would result in changes in the layout of ships, although it's a neat idea. (Battleship armor floats in mercury! In general, ships would have to be designed closer to rafts than a standard ship, with little-to-nothing below the mercuryline.) This also would have toxic fumes... which would be in and of itself interesting for the warp.

Answer (score 2):

**It is shallow.**

Only a couple of meters deep in most places.  You can see the bottom.  With the wind, even a low draft boat will sometimes scrape.  Way too shallow for submarines.

Comment: shallow water-seas deep enough for battleships would still allow for sleek subs, especially if they cannot be hunted from the air. You should merge with @Commoner to get shallow mercury-seas : 1m of draft in mercury equals 13 meters of draft in water - so 2m mercury would suffice for battleships to prance around in.

Comment: @bukwyrm - these are actually battlerafts.  But they still get called battleships because some of the sailors thought "battlerafts" was a hurtful term.

Answer (score 1):

*Things*.

If you're going off of Warhammer 40k - which has a very interesting concept of the Warp - hostile and unpleasant *things* live in the Warp.

How this is different from 40k: the *things* have to crawl out of the "ocean" to attack surface ships, meaning they can easily be defeated, but submarine combatants are on *their* turf - and *they* do horrific things when they manage to breach a ship hull.

Submarines are suicide. Nobody builds or uses them. Even unmanned vehicles get attacked.

Answer (score 0):

Its foamy. Or an ultra low density fluid (not water)

A sea with a lot of foam, or dissolved gasses, at all depths, or very low average density, would not provide buoyancy. Submarines and other objects would simply sink to the bottom and become mired in the mud or whatever else was there, and die.

Comment: Wouldn't this sink surface ships too?

Comment: Probably. But solves your submarine issue.